# pass multiple parameters to controller from route in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to pass multiple parameters from route to controller in laravel5.

ie,My route is ,

```
Route::get('quotations/pdf/{id}/{is_print}', 'QuotationController@generatePDF');
```

and My controller is,

```
   public function generatePDF($id, $is_print = false) {
        $data = array(
            'invoice' => Invoice::findOrFail($id),
            'company' => Company::firstOrFail()
        );
        $html = view('pdf_view.invoice', $data)->render();
        if ($is_print) {
            return $this->pdf->load($html)->show();
        }
        $this->pdf->filename($data['invoice']->invoice_number . ".pdf");
        return $this->pdf->load($html)->download();
    }
```

If user want to download `PDF`, the `URL` will be like this,

```
/invoices/pdf/26
```

If user want to print the `PDF`,the `URL` will be like this,

```
 /invoices/pdf/26/print  or /invoices/print/26
```

How it is possibly in laravel5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the url in your route or in your example is invalid, in one place you use `quotations` and in the other `invoices`

Usually you don't want to duplicate urls to the same action but if you really need it, you need to create extra route:

```
Route::get('invoices/print/{id}', 'QuotationController@generatePDF2');
```

and add new method in your controller

```
public function generatePDF2($id) {
   return $this->generatePDF($id, true);
}
```